# How to loop the formcontrolname dynamically along with validation

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

I want to validate the multiple looping of dynamic formControlName="xxx" in select field

My html code

```
<ul *ngFor="let detaillist of stressli.stresstabdetails;">
    <li>
        <div class="form-container">
            <select [(ngModel)]="detaillist.stressname" class="form-control" formControlName="spotstressname {{q + 1 }}">
                <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected>Select an option</option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of stressdata;" [ngValue]="item">{{item}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

TS file validation:

```
this.CaseDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  spotstressname1:['', Validators.required],
  spotstressname2:['', Validators.required],
});
```

In .ts file I hardcoded the spotstressname1, spotstressname2, etc.
Instead of hardcoded value I need dynamically as Output. How can I get that?

Comment: Check [formArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray)

Answer (score 2):

**First of all... DON'T use ngModel with reactive forms, you need to decide whether you want to use ngModel or reactive forms, not both!**

Here in this sample we go full reactive. So how to create your formcontrols dynamically... I would do:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.CaseDetailsForm = this.fb.group({});
}

ngOnInit() {
  // add dynamic form controls named 'spotstressname' and index
  this.stressli.stresstabdetails.map((x, i) => {
    this.CaseDetailsForm.addControl('spotstressname'+i, this.fb.control(x.stressname))
  })
}
```

Then in the template we can use the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#description) pipe to iterate the form controls of the form in the template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let ctrl of CaseDetailsForm.controls | keyvalue">
  <select [formControlName]="ctrl.key">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of stressdata;" [value]="item">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1q9w9?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Kindly help me with , i want exactly like yours but along with validation of select option values while submitting the form.

Comment: If you want validation after submit, I can suggest following: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9tkhb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thanks for your reply.

Your using array data inside the .ts file. But am not able get same output by using 
 same data from JSON file.

Am calling JSON data by using services. Its in nested array object

Comment: Please fork my stackblitz and mock the http-request, you can do it by using rxjs `of`. I'll be happy to take a look at the stackblitz :)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.data = [
   {
     controlName: 'Username',
     controlType: 'text',
     valueType: 'text',
     placeholder: 'Enter username',
     validators: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 5
    }
   },  
  {
    controlName: 'Deposit From',
    controlType: 'date',
    valueType: 'date',
    placeholder: 'Deposit From',
    modelVal:"depositFrom",
    validators: {
      required: true
    }
  }];

this.data.forEach(formControl => {
      formGroup[formControl.controlName] = new FormControl('');
    });
```